# Why ajax request is getting aborted ....?

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I am sending ajax request to server

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: checkin_push,
    url: api_url + 'file.php?token=' + last_token + '&date=' + dated,
    dataType: "json",
    timeout: 100000, // 100 seconds
    success: function(data) {
        // invoke sync
        api_pending_sync = true;            
        // checkin back to home
        $.mobile.changePage('#home', { reverse: true });
        //api_sync_message
        $('#sync-message').fadeIn(300).html('<div class="ui-body ui-body-e ui-corner-all" style="margin-bottom: 20px;" data-theme="d">Successfully checked in for ' + checkin_display_date() + '.</div>').fadeOut(5000);
    },
    complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
    },
    error: function() {
        $('#checkin-status-message').fadeIn(300).html('<div class="ui-body ui-body-e ui-corner-all" style="margin-bottom: 20px; color: red;" data-theme="d">Unable to Check In, Please check your internet connection and try again.</div>').fadeOut(5000);
    }
});
```

Here is relevant code of file.php

```
     =========rest code -=================

    #------------------- send alert to life lines (send alerts) -------------------

$query = query("SELECT email, phone, sms_carrier FROM table WHERE account_id = ".escape($account_id));
if ((mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) and $send_alert) 
{
   while ($l = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lifelines)) 
   {

           // send mail 
           /* this function is returning value of mail() function*/
       send_alert_email($userEmail, $sms_email, 'alert-2');

   }
}
#-------------------------------(/alerts)--------------------------------------

$return = array('answers' => $answers); //, 'transact' => $checkin_transact);
 }

 json_out($return);

 ?>
```

Now what exactly happening is .. if control is coming in while loop and email is getting send the firebug shows status as 'aborted' otherwise it is working fine ...
what am I doing wrong..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sometimes sending emails taking long time (and you are sending many of them), so probably you exceed php execution time.

Comment: there are no such functions as json_out and escape, unless they're defined by you?

Comment: u can test the php file with a sample POST form, just to be sure- its working fine

Comment: @Ziarno they are user defined ..

Comment: @AviC yes I have done that its working fine

Comment: can u only send parameters in- data:  ,instead of adding url: parameters? not both of them!

Comment: @Avi, you actually can. It is still a POST request, but PHP will extract parameters from the query string and provide them in $_GET as if the request method actually was GET.

Comment: Is it executing upto 100 sec? if yes then it will be aborted after timout

Answer (score 1):

Can you replace the following line:

```
error: function() {
```

with the following:

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
```

and check the value of `textStatus` and `errorThrown` to see what was the error when the request aborted.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: checkin_push,
    url: api_url + 'file.php?token=' + last_token + '&date=' + dated,
    ...
```

You are sending both GET & POST parameters. So, just want to make sure, you are not getting `null` for any parameter.

**In file.php,**

make sure to get the `token` and `date` values as `$_GET`

& `checkin_push` sent parameter-values as `$_POST`

or

get all the sent parameters values as `$_REQUEST`